# Google Analytic Tracking code with multiple website in subdirectory

Tags: google-analytics

I have many website with the same domain name but those are in sub-directory
Every website in sub-directory has there own Google analytic tracking code. if there is the correct way to work with the below example

exmaple.

www.mywebsite.com/clothshop

www.mywebsite.com/computershop

www.mywebsite.com/phoneshoop

those are with difference design and 3-partiy check-out cart.
this is What i am using but it not working

i placed the code on my own domain www.mywebsite.com

```
    <script>

  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-xxx', 'auto');
  ga('create', 'UA-xxx1', 'auto', {'name': 'closthstore'});
  ga('create', 'UA-xxx2', 'auto', {'name': 'computerstore'});
  ga('create', 'UA-xxx3', 'auto', {'name': 'phnoeshop'});
  ga('send', 'pageview');
  ga('closthsotre.send', 'pageview');
  ga('computerstore.send', 'pageview');
  ga('phnomshop.send', 'pageview');
  ga('require', 'linker');
  ga('linker:autoLink', ['3-party-check-out-cart.com']);

</script>
```

Comment: What isn't working? Also, are your tracking codes different or are they the same?

Comment: thank you so much for helping. In each UA code that contain in sub-directory website "www.mywebsite.com/clothshop" is the same one UA code in the main website 'www.mywebsite.com". 
what not work is traffic tracking. example:
www.mywebsite.com/closthstore/ which referral from facebook.com
when user click buy one product it redirect to 3-party-check-out-cart.com and that referral traffic from facebook.com it change to (direct) . it not keep the same referral traffic as the original source from facebook.com 
is there anything wrong with above code?

Comment: OK, so you're saying that the referrer information is not being captured for your `/closthstore` page, or your `3-party-check-out-cart.com` pages? If it is the 3rd party, you gotta have the require linker for _each_ tracker you set. Eg. `ga('closthstore.require', 'linker');`

Comment: No problem. You'll both the require and the linker:autolink if I remember correctly.

Comment: Thank once again! let me try one by one